# Jquery: Check for 'ok' clicks on confirm() popup dialogues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have a couple of confirm dialogues in my app that fire off when users try to delete items. Is there any way to check if a user clicks on the 'ok' button globally on ALL confirm dialogues so that I can run a function?
   I've tried searching around, but cant find anything which would help me do this.

Comment: IIRC If it the user clicks ok the confirm will return true, if the user clicks no it will return false, and if the user exits by clicking the x it will return null. Something like that anyway. Just make a demo and monitor what the possible outcomes are, then test for those outcomes. If it is a matter of storing the outcomes and checking if all are true, well that would be a simple `if(confirm1 && confirm2 && confirm3) doThing();`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable and assign it to the return value of confirm()

```
function myFunction() {
        var myVar = confirm("Press Ok or Cancel");

}
```

You will get either true or false depending if the user clicks ok or cancel respectively.

So if you have multiple confirm() you can for example push each variable to an array and check if all the values are true.
Hope it helps :)